# Can kitchen plumbing run behind cabinet and not in wall?

Tags: plumbing, kitchens

Normally, plumbing (drain and supply) runs inside wall, but is it permitted, by national building code, to run plumbing between wall and cabinet (not inside wall)?

Below is a crude cartoon of what I want to do.

**UPDATE:** This means moving entire row of cabinet forward ~2" as well as horizontal run of supply/drain/vent (not shown but very important).  This drawing is simply to illustrate the cavity in which I want to run plumbing, not the full plumbing layout.

[image]

Comment: If you have freezing temps, I would do that, even if not in code, on an external wall.  I believe code only deals with how the plumbing is put together, not where it goes in a house.  So having a toilet in the middle of living room is kinky but in code, if done right.

Comment: It already does that, just look under the sink

Comment: "_is it permitted, by national building code,_" depends an awful lot on which nation you're talking about... there's nearly 200 to choose from.

Comment: Can you clarify what's happening with the cabinet here?  Are you intending to shift the entire cabinet forward, off the wall—and is this a row of cabinets, or a single sink base?  Or trim off X amount off the back and have the front flush with adjacent cabinets?

Comment: The update leads directly to the code violation. Vents must run vertically (meaning 45-90° by definition) until 6" above the flood rim of the fixtures served. Running a horizontal vent below countertop level is not OK. You might (depending on situation) be able to use Island Venting with it's own set of requirements to solve that - you might not. Since you've left the details of that vague, no way to speculate, but it's certainly the elephant in the room that makes this project unlikely to pass inspection. You could run the vent at the required height exposed on the face of the wall.

Comment: I don't understand why you can't just put the cabinets back against the wall and have the plumbing in front of the cabinet back wall, like a normal person.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<strike>No code issue with it.</strike> Well, other than - your drawing does not incude a required vent. But as to in the wall or in front of the wall, code does not care.

**You have updated** to indicate that a horizontal run of vent is intended in the space behind the cabinets. **That would be a code violation**, as both UPC and IPC require that such runs of vents be *at least 6" above the flood rim of fixtures served* (or similar language) and the flood rim of a sink in a countertop is at countertop level, with this vent pipe located below that level. Apart from the special case of "Island Venting" with its own set of rules, that is **strictly forbidden.**

A waste of space if you're leaving a gap behind all the cabinets to make room for plumbing behind one, and the sort of "dead space" that often attracts unwelcome guests.

You can simply run the plumbing through the bottom (and upper back for the vent, typically) of the cabinet, rather than running it behind.

Comment: I understand your point about dead space, including unwanted guests.  On vent, I did not show, but vent (rather than AAV) is part reason for this scheme. I'm wondering about your point about bottom of the cabinet though: you mean lay plumbing on the floor, and slot the cabinet bottom rails?

Comment: Standard cabinets always have dead space on the back side, no?

Comment: @akostadinov standard cabinets usually only have a few eighths of an inch of dead space, depending on their construction.

Comment: @codechimp I mean drill through the bottom of the cabinet and the floor to run the pipe down to the turn to along the joist below, without trying to "hide" any of it behind the cabinet.

Comment: @Huesmann, in my country (Bulgaria) I see like 5-10cm space behind cabinet to the wall. Probably related to avoiding mold but not sure.